# Google Home - Signin status is CANCELLED when sign in with google home and 'personal results' setting disabled

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I am developing account linking and I have a problem with google home in a certain case.

I have a DialogFlow intent that calls this code when i say "log in" :

```
export function signIn(app) {
  app.ask(new SignIn());
}
```

I have another DialogFlow intent that has "actions_intent_SIGN_IN" event and calls this code :

```
export function signInConfirmation(app, params, signin) {
  if (signin && signin.status === 'OK') {
    chatAsk(app, 'A');
  } else if (signin && signin.status === 'CANCELLED') {
    chatAsk(app, 'B');
  } else {
    chatAsk(app, 'C');
  }
}
```

Everything works fine with google home and google assistant : after logging in, the assistant answers "A".

However, when I [disable the "Personal Results" setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqCER.png) on google home, the signin object of the signInConfirmation method has a status equal to 'CANCELLED' and I dont understand why.

I tried to authenticate (with this setting disabled) on applications available on the Google store and they all seem to handle this case: the assistant says something like : "In order to display different content, I need your permission to access your personal informations ... " and it sends a notification in the google home app to change the setting.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, do you still have this issue? Do you also get the message "Personal results need to be enabled"? Or do you get a different message?

Comment: The discussion was continued in the github thread[1]. And according to last message[2] issue was solved.


  [1]: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/231
  [2]: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/231#issuecomment-479946108